# Hover direction according to container size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hoverintent

I would like to alter the hover direction based on the container size, if there's not enough space on the container to show the hover to the right, it should then show on the left.

See fiddle for details:

## http://jsfiddle.net/jHgkp/3/

I use hoverIntent, but FULL details are on the Fiddle above:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".discover").hoverIntent({
                over: makeVisible,
                out: makeInvisible,
                timeout: 200
                });
            }); // close document.ready

            function makeVisible() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(100);}
            function makeInvisible() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut(300);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approches.

1) You can style the tooltip on the third element to show on the left side (not dynamic)

2) You can take the element offest().left + element.width + the tooltip width and compare it with the holder width. (dynamic)

3) Yo can the the tooltip offest + width and directly compare it to the holder width. (dynamic)

It depends what exactly you want...

This is the only JS added.

```
var holderWidth = $('.container').outerWidth();
```

and

```
//where 260 is left 150 + width 110
var pos = $(this).offset().left + 260
if(holderWidth < pos){
    $(this).addClass('leftPos');
}else{
    $(this).removeClass('leftPos');
}
```

and 1 line of css:

```
.leftPos ul { left: auto; right: 150px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jHgkp/4/)

Comment: I'm sorry for being a leecher, but is it possible you could make the changes on the fiddle so I can study it?

Comment: I can't thank you enough, it's incredible how a few lines of code can make miracles! I Must learn javascript. I've made some modifications to the script, because the middle column was hovering to the left, and it needed to be on the right whenever possible. No matter what value I added to the original script the first and the middle column were always hovering or to the left or to the right, together. So this is what I came up with: http://pastebin.com/WumwsgwJ (Come to that using document.write (pos);) Thanks a lot for your time drip!!